# Why this Palindrome Recursive Function giving me True in all cases?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, palindrome

I have tried to write a recursive version of the Palindrome function. But it is giving me **True** in all the cases. why?

```
def isPalindrome(inputString):
   if len(inputString)==0 or 1:
      return True
   elif inputString[0]==inputString[-1]:
      return isPalindrome(inputString[1:-1])
   else:
      return False
```

Why **False** is not working for non Palindrome Text.

[image]

Comment: `if len(inputString)==0 or 1:` is not the right way to test multiple values.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/494134

Comment: oh Okay. Thank you so much for this information.

Answer (score 1):

Short circuit evaluation.

```py
def is_palindrome(input_string):
    if len(input_string) == 0 or len(input_string) == 1:
        return True
    elif input_string[0] == input_string[-1]:
        return is_palindrome(input_string[1:-1])
    else:
        return False


print(is_palindrome('your_string')) # False
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The above code is working. But where I was wrong in the above code?

Comment: That was quick! I got it where I was making mistake.